# Automapper using ForPath in ForAllMaps

Tags: c#, dictionary, automapper, reverse

I want to set a condition on all the paths in my map, where if the path specific source property is null, I need to skip the mapping.

I am trying to do something like the below:

```
config.CreateMap<BarChartOptions,Settings>().ReverseMap();              
config.ForAllMaps((maps, expression) => {

  var paths = maps.PathMaps;
  foreach(var path in paths) {          
    //maps.ForPath(path,o=>o.Condition(c=>c.SourceMember != null));
    //expression.ForPath(path,o=>o.Condition(c=>c.SourceMember != null));
  }

});
```

But none of the two options is working, is there a way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Automapper has the option to specify which MemberList it'll use, that is basically to set which properties should match, from source or destination. So maybe something like this?

```
config.ForAllMaps((maps, expression) => maps.ConfiguredMemberList = MemberList.Source);
```